# Struggling with Parameterized Insert Query

Tags: c#, mysql, parameters, insert, odbc

I'm really struggling with creating a parameterized insert query in C# using OdbcConnection and MySQL.  If I use string concatenation in the SQL statement it works fine.  However, I need to accept user input from a textbox and this is vulnerable to SQL injection.

When I try to setup the parameterized query the command sorta works.  A record is inserted into the database so I know the connection is being made and a record is able to be inserted.  The issue is all the inserted field values are null as if it's not reading the parameters.

The following code works:

```
public static void Insert(string connectionString, Vendor vendor)
{
     using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
     {
          string SQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_vendor (name) VALUES (\"" + vendor.Name + "\")";
          using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(SQL, connection))
          {
               connection.Open();
               command.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
     }
}
```

The following code inserts an empty record:

```
public static void Insert(string connectionString, Vendor vendor)
{
     using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
     {
          string SQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_vendor (name) VALUES (@name)";
          using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(SQL, connection))
          {
               OdbcParameter parameter = new OdbcParameter("@name", vendor.Name);
               command.Parameters.Add(parameter)

               connection.Open();
               command.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
     }
}
```

I've tried a million different variations of the above code.  They all seem to work but each time they only insert an empty record.  I'm probably missing something obvious and making things more complicated than they need to be but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you rtied with a hadrcoded `SQL` string (e.g. `INSERT INTO tbl_vendor (name) VALUES ('test')`)?

Comment: You need to set the value to parameter: `parameter.Value = 'Something' before calling the ExecuteNonQuery method.

Comment: You can try with this sql string `string SQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_vendor (name) VALUES (?)";` and using this parameter `OdbcParameter parameter = new OdbcParameter("?", vendor.Name);`

Comment: AHA!!  Hackerman's suggestion is the one that finally worked.  Using the ? mark instead of the named parameter worked although it's slightly more confusing than using named parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Test specifying the dataType:

```
OdbcParameter parameter = new OdbcParameter("@name", OdbcType.VarChar);
parameter.Value = vendor.Name;
command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```